# Ritenersi + subjunctive clause not introduced by "che"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

In [this article on COVID-19](https://www.liceotosi.edu.it/lavocedeglistudenti/2021/01/02/il-covid-19-e-la-nuova-peste/), we have:

> Inoltre, pensando al 1630, ci si immagina un mondo buio, tra lazzaretti dove venivano ricoverati i malati e figure dei presunti untori che si riteneva diffondessero volontariamente la malattia...

> *Also, considering 1630, one imagines a gloomy world, with the sick recovering in quarantine hospitals, and the alleged 'untori' who were thought to have intentionally spread the plague...*

My question is around the construction ritenersi + subjunctive, without an intervening "che" — is this syntax permitted in Italian, and if so, what is its stylistic effect?

Comment: A note: _ricoverare_ does not mean “to recover”. It's a false friend (known to deceive people in both directions). Instead, _ricoverare_ means “to shelter, to admit (to hospital), to hospitalise”.

Comment: @Gae.S.: Quite, but not even that. It's just the verb _ritenere_, which can be used in several different ways: _ritengo che Luigi abbia torto_, _ti ritengo un buon amico_, _mi ritengo un buon amico_, _si ritiene che X sia un buon amico_... But the same holds – with the due differences – for more or less all transitive verbs: _mangio a casa_, _ti mangio_ (as said to a steak), _qui si mangiano buone bistecche_, _qui si mangia bene_ and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is fine; sometimes we omit the "*che*" in order to avoid repetitions ("*presunti untori **che** si riteneva (che) diffondessero*") or, more rarely, just to keep the sentence shorter ("*si ritiene siano stati i primi a...*" = "it is believed they were the first to...").

Usually we can omit the "*che*" when in the subjunctive clause the subject is implied; if the subject is explicitly mentioned, omitting the "*che*" does not sound quite right.

E.g.

1. *Lucy è l'ominide più famoso al mondo. Si ritiene (che) sia morta di sfinimento.*
   Lucy is the World's most famous hominid. It is believed she died by exhaustion.
2. *Si ritiene **che** Lucy, l'ominide più famoso al mondo, sia morta di sfinimento.*
   It is believed that Lucy - the World's most famous hominid - died by exhaustion.

Comment: [At Treccani Encyclopedia](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-oggettive_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) you can find a source that supports what is said in this answer.